# Dynamic CSS grid: 3 cols in a row and 1 full width col on random positions

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to achieve a dynamic CSS grid layout where some columns with class 'featured' for example are going to expand on full width of the row and the other columns which don't have this class will stay and flow into 3 cols in a row layout.

But in my case is that if we take the second column for example and it becomes with class 'featured', then this column should expand full-width on the next row and then the flow of the columns to become - col 3 takes the place of col 2 and col 4 to come one row above and takes the position of col 3.

So it will become something like this afterwards:
col 3 becomes col2, col 4 goes one position up and goes on the position of col 3, col 2 (class 'featured') is going full width on the next row, then col 5 going on col 4 position and etc. And that's the concept from where I put class 'featured' on specific columns on the grid there to follow that same layout dynamic flow. Please refer to the attached mockup for reference.

[Image Mockup for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2frT.jpg)

Thank you. Hope someone can help me achieve this.
Best regards, Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this easily with css grid. They key would be to use `grid-auto-flow: dense` and then just add `grid-column: 1 / -1` to the grid cell that you want to feature.

I have created a small demonstration here (click "Run code snippet" to see it work):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#btn');
const target = document.querySelector('#target');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    target.classList.toggle('featured');    
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: .5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.cell {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cell.featured {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div id="target" class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Toggle featured</button>
```

You can click the button to toggle a "featured" class on the 3rd grid.
When it has the "featured" class it takes the whole row and the other cells take the available space.

(you won't need the JS. that is just for this demonstration)

i hope this is what you wanted...